# Will be "Domain Shared contacts API" turned down like Contacts API on June 2021?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We received from google-developer email asking us to "Migrate your Contacts API to People API before June 15, 2021, to ensure error-free API calls; API calls will otherwise return 100% errors by December 15, 2021.".
Contacts Api (https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3) needs the following scope:
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/
and the support asked to abandon it.
But this is the same https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/ of the Domain Shared Contact API.
So my question is: can we continue to use Domain Shared Contact API?
thk Federica

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the [Contacts API documentation](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3):

> **Warning:** The Shared Contacts API is intended only for external contacts. Using this API to create contact information for domain users or groups can result in duplicate contact information for those users and groups, which may lead to unexpected behavior.

The docs on [Domain Shared Contacts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts) don't mention anything about deprecation. THe Domain Shared Contacts API is a part of the Admin SDK which is a completely different API, so I think it's safe to assume this will continue to work without issue.